# Why does the 'LeaderNotAvailable' error occur when trying to increase the number of partitions in a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've tried different strategies but can't figure out why Kafka can't assign a leader for new partitions

This is what the broker logs look like:

```
[2023-12-03 09:02:34,000] ERROR [KafkaApi-1] Error when processing request (sessionId=1, epoch=100): 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.LeaderNotAvailableException: Leader not available for partition 0
    at org.apache.kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.handleLeaderNotAvailable(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:741)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:497)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.run(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:255)
```

I would be grateful for any answers.

I used the latest version, so this is not the error. I checked the status of the broker, so this is not the error.

Comment: "Partition 0" shouldn't be a "new partition". If you use `kafka-topics --describe`, what do you see? Have you looked at logs of the broker that should be the leader?